# Bootstrap Contact Form - Wont Show Success Message on Same Page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

The problem is that the contact form redirects me to another page with the success message instead of being shown on the same page as indicated by the code.

Here is the HTML part:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="contact.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <! Will be used to display an alert to the user>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the php:

```
    <?php
    if ($_POST["submit"]) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'example@domain.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

        $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5) {
            $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

I've tried the fixes that has been posted here by other users but none of them work.

Thanks!

Comment: Edited again, 1 error remaining which has nothing to do with the duplicate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the variable is defined with isset()

```
  if (!isset($errName) && !isset($errEmail) && !isset($errMessage) && !isset($errHuman)) {
        // do stuff
    }
```

Comment: I tried that, still get the error: "Notice: Undefined variable" on line 64, 71, 78,85 and no e-mail gets sent out.